# Same element locators under different parents

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, page-objects, css-selectors

This is more of a "code review" question but it is very SQA specific so posting it here.

There are two different menus on a page: "left" and "right" both containing "save" and "cancel" buttons with the *same exact markup representation*. To avoid repeating selectors (we have [this lint rule](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/no-repetitive-selectors.md) enabled) this was written:

```
var DiffPage = function () {
    this.leftMenu = ".leftDiff_control" + " ";
    this.rightMenu = ".rightDiff_control" + " ";

    this.saveBtn = ".save__button .btn-primary";
    this.cancelBtn = ".save__button .btn-default";

    this.leftSaveBtn = element(by.css(this.leftMenu + this.saveBtn));
    this.rightSaveBtn = element(by.css(this.rightMenu + this.saveBtn));
    this.leftCancelBtn = element(by.css(this.leftMenu + this.cancelBtn));
    this.rightCancelBtn = element(by.css(this.rightMenu + this.cancelBtn));
}
```

I don't particularly like string-concatenating CSS selectors here and, also, think there is still repetition but on a different level. Is there a better way to address the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've just got that [*rubber-duck debugging effect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and figured out one way to make it beautiful.

We just need to move the menu into *its own page object* and re-use:

```
var MenuPage = function (locator) {
    this.container = element(by.css(locator));

    this.saveBtn = this.container.element(by.css(".save__button .btn-primary"));
    this.cancelBtn = this.container.element(by.css(".save__button .btn-default"));
};
```

Then, we could have `MenuPage` pages defined as child page objects of the parent diff page:

```
var DiffPage = function () {
    this.leftMenu = new MenuPage(".leftDiff_control");
    this.rightMenu = new MenuPage(".rightDiff_control");
};
```

And then use it in a test like:

```
var diffPage = new DiffPage();

diffPage.leftMenu.saveBtn.click();
diffPage.rightMenu.cancelBtn.click();
```